# Counting the number of elements in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am new to MATLAB. Suppose I have a vector like x = [1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0]. I want to calculate the total number of elements in the vector and the number of non zero elements in the vector. Then come up with a ratio of both the numbers. I am searching in MATLAB help. how to do count of elements, but till now I didn't get any luck. If anyone provide me with help, it would be of great help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get the number of elements with [`numel(x)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/numel.html).

You can get the number of non-zeros with `sum(x ~= 0)`.

So the ratio is one divided by the other.

Comment: @Oli: Thanks for your quick response, I am using the all(x==1) to check whether vector x has all non zero elements or not. But even if I have a vector like x = [0 0 0 0 0 0 ], all (x==1) gives me a TRUE value, can you tell me why it does so?

Comment: @user: That gives me false, not true.

Comment: Ohh...sorry my bad...suppose i wanted to check whether all my elements are zero will all(x==0) would work?

Comment: @user: Yes, that would work.  Alternatively, `~any(x)` would work.

Comment: @Oli: A faster approach to non-zero elements that works _only_ for Boolean vectors such as this one, is the inner product. If `x` is a column vector, `x'*x` gives the same answer as `nnz` or `sum()` and is an order of magnitude faster.

Answer (score 4):

The right way to find the number of nonzero elements (in general) is to use the `nnz()` function; using `sum()` also works in this *particular* case but will fail if there are numbers other than zero and one in the matrix used. Therefore to calculate the total element count, nonzero element count, and ratio, use code like this:

```
x = [1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0];
nonzeroes = nnz(x);
total = numel(x);
ratio = nonzeroes / total;
```

Answer (score 2):

The ratio of non-zero elements to all elements in a vector is:

```
r = length(find(x)) / length(x)
```

What `length` does is kind of obvious. `find` gives you the index of all non-zero elements.

*Edit:* Fixed mistake of using size instead of length.

Comment: No, because `size` doesn't give you a scalar!

Comment: @Darhuuk: Removed -1.  But `numel` is a more general solution than even `length` (consider what happens if `x` is a matrix, not a vector).

Comment: @Oli-Charlesworth Good point, I was thinking the same when you typed your comment and already updated my answer to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

`a= numel(find(x))/numel(x)`  is another way to do it.